# CSS issue in Firefox

Tags: php, mysql, html, css, firefox

I've created mini content management system for workers of small company. This management system works with CKeditor. The ssmall group of users create new page with CKeditor (it's WYSWYG) and submit data into db.

Now the problem is, there is a css issue. Take a look at this page http://smiths-heimann.az/?page=171 and here are the results

The result from **Google Chrome 14**
[image]

**Opera 11**

[image: http://prntscr.com/3g81s]

**IE 9**

[image]

and **Firefox 7**

[image]

How to fix that problem on Firefox? There are hundreds of page with this problem in mysql db table. Is there anyway to find and fix wrong css code in db table with php function? How to fix this error in CKEdior 3.6?

Answer (score 0):

add css property **background-repeat: no-repeat;** in css to the concerning li

Comment: As i said, it's code written by CKeditor. The problem is how can i fix that problem from root?

Comment: you can fix it from root by modifying the CKeditor code where the inline styles are set for <li> tags. An easier and quicker solution is to add UL.prdinf LI { background-repeat: no-repeat; } to your css file.
if this rule gets ignored, add "!important" to it

Answer (score 0):

The only issue is that the background is repeating for all the `<LI>` tags.  Just add this CSS:

```
UL.prdinf LI {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: As i said, it's code written by CKeditor. The problem is how can i fix that problem from root?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're setting this on those `li` elements (..using a massive `style` attribute!):

```
background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
```

It should just be `background-repeat: no-repeat`.

Firefox is evidently being more strict about rejecting invalid input than other browsers.

Comment: As i said, it's code written by CKeditor. The problem is how can i fix that problem from root?

Comment: You've already been given the answer, just add to your CSS file: `.prdinf li {
    background-repeat: no-repeat
}`. Although `no-repeat no-repeat` is set inline, which would usually override that, it's not an issue in this case because the invalid declaration is being ignored.

Comment: As far as correcting the CKEditor code goes, I have no idea. If a WYSIWYG editor is generating junk like `background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat`, something is wrong with it. Someone else had the same problem as you: http://help.pixelandtonic.com/brandonkelly/topics/background_repeat_fails_in_custom_style_in_firefox?from_gsfn=true.

Comment: "Although no-repeat no-repeat is set inline" That's what i'm talking about. The css code will beignored because of inline style

Comment: No, it won't. The inline style is completely ignored by Firefox because it's invalid.